# What is the difference in building ISVForce apps vs Force.com embedded?

Tags: isv, force.com-embedded

I understand the licensing model between these two partner programs and what to use based on the needs.

I wanted to understand how developing force.com embedded differs from ISVforce. Is the difference only during the packaging stage? How do we packages force.com embedded apps? How do we sell them? etc etc.

Can we create an app on ISVForce and also have it available as force.com embedded with minimal effort?

I am finding it difficult to find resources related to force.com embedded. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: This question was asked when I was very new to the platform. There is no real difference in building apps for ISV and Embedded. Its just how you market it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of Force.com Embedded is 'Remedyforce'. BMC has existing software 'Remedy'. Recently it has been migrated to force.com platform as 'Remedyforce'. BMC sells 'Remedyforce' to new/existing customers who may not have salesforce.com in first place. If customer has Salesforce.com Org; the 'Remedyforce' app can be installed to existing Org. Otherwise a new org with 'Remedyforce' is created. In both the cases; 'Remedyforce' related revenue flows from customer to BMC; BMC intern pays Salesforce for using it's platform. End customer has no relation with Salesforce.

The point is, if there is an app which can exist on it's own; it's an Force.com Embedded App. Otherwise it's an ISVForce app.

Can we create an app on ISVForce and also have it available as force.com embedded with minimal effort?
Ans:- Technically, both apps are similar; it's just revenue model that differs.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. So, how do we go about creating an Embedded app? Is it the same way as ISV force? How do we create an app that exists on its own? How do we package an embedded app?

Comment: When I say an app which exists on it's own means - from business point of view you can buy package like 'remedyforce' but do not need  Salesforce Sales/Service Cloud. While an 'Email to Case' enhancement app doesn't make sense without having Service Cloud in first place. As far as packaging is concerned; it will be too broad to cover here.

Comment: Are there any blog posts or references that cover the Force.com Embedded topic in more detail?